# Laravel 4 - How to inject an instance of something that is bound to the container into a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to to inject an instance of a class that is managed via the IoC container, and is bound using a service provider. The register() method is as follows and contains a lot of the fluff in setting up this object:

```
  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bind('GoogleAnalytics', function($app)
    {
      if(!\File::exists(\Config::get('analytics.certificate_path')))
      {
        throw new \Exception("Can't find the .p12 certificate in: " . \Config::get('analytics.certificate_path'));
      }

      $config = array(
        'oauth2_client_id' => \Config::get('analytics.client_id'),
        'use_objects' => \Config::get('analytics.use_objects'),
      );

      $client = new \Google_Client($config);

      // $client->setAccessType('offline');

      $client->setAssertionCredentials(
        new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
          \Config::get('analytics.service_email'),
          \Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY,
          file_get_contents(\Config::get('analytics.certificate_path'))
        )
      );

      return new Analytics($client);
    });
  }
```

Then in my controller I want this to automatically be pass in through the constructor through IoC, although this doesn't work and I get a ReflectionException: Class not found error.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController {
  protected $analytics;

  public function __construct(GoogleAnalytics $analytics) {
        $this->analytics = $analytics;      
  }
```

I'm under the impression that this should be possible? [The comment by thepsion5 here](http://laravel.io/forum/04-30-2014-ioc-binding-closure-vs-automatic-resolution#reply-6180) also seems to suggest that this should work. Ignoring other issues (like use of Repository etc.) any ideas on what's going wrong for me?

As always any help/ideas is greatly appreciated, and a big thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Verify the ServiceProvider is loaded. Add a `die('Provider runs');` at the top of your register method. Also, run a `composer dumpautoload` to make sure all files are found.

Comment: I can confirm that the ServiceProvider runs, both by adding that die() at the top, and also I can `$app->make('GoogleAnalytics')` within routes.php and dump that object okay.

I have forgotten `composer dumpautoload` a few times, but this time that's not the cause.

Comment: @SamLeicester This looks like namespace problem. Check/show the namespaces you use.

Comment: Further to the comment by @JarekTkaczyk try putting a \ in front of the type hint.

Comment: Did you add your service providers to the array of service providers in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk you also correctly guessed the issue. Cheers folks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When auto-injecting via type-hinting, the type-hint MUST exist. Does the `GoogleAnalytics` class/interface exist in your case? I'm guessing not.

Also, if you're namespacing, keep in mind that you have to `app->bind('Full\Namespace\ClassName', ...)` because all classnames inside a string are treated as if they were in the global namespace.

Comment: That's where I was slipping, the namespace, the class did exist but just not within the global namespace. Makes a lot of sense now that it's been spelled out. Thanks :-)